# Laravel Access Layout in service provider

Tags: php, laravel, layout, service, laravel-4

this is my service provider code :

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

class LayoutVarsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {

    }


    public function boot()
    {
        $route = Route::currentRouteAction();
        $parts = explode("@" , $route);

        Event::listen('Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher', function($event)
        {
            if($parts[0] = 'IndexController'){
                switch($parts[1]) {
                    case 'getIndex':
                        $this->app->layout->container_class = 'homepage';
                        break;

                    case 'getHowworks':
                        $this->app->layout->container_class = 'how-does-it-work';
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I want to be able to get current controller or current layout which is loaded in my service provider by using Laravel Event Dispatch I was able to get controller name and acion name from Laravel Face Route.but how to access layout ???
I already know that all service providers extend Service provider and service Provider class has a property called app and this way we have access to laravel IOC.

Solved .

after all my problem has been solved but yet I don't know how to access controller instance which has been dispatched.
and as I have read container and controller and service provider source code it's impossible . maybe I should extend laravel container myself.

Comment: Can you give some background on why you'd want to do this as there might be a simpler option? I've done this before in symfony2 but doesn't look like you have a lot of events from the lifecycle to work with in Laravel to grab the controller http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle#application-events

Comment: I have so many pages in my project and my layout has a div with id of container and in each page it has specific class for example in contact page it is like this : "<div id='contentainer' class='contact' ></div>" and I think its not a good work to pass these class names in every action on all controllers I want to have a switch case to set the container class upon the route and controller and action which is dispatched.

Comment: Basically if I were you I'd just make a helper function to use in your view to look up the controller/action in a config file get the value and apply the CSS class. It still seems dodgy but your original idea is a bad way to go

Comment: can explain more and write your idea as an answer because I think its a good idea but I'm a little confused what to do and if I get what you mean and I solve my problem mark your answer as accepted answer . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so basically define your config (example name class.php) as something like

```
return [
    'IndexController@getIndex' => 'homepage',
    'IndexController@getHowworks' => 'how-does-it-work'
];
```

Then you can create a helper function in a seperate file but as we're using a Laravel config we might as well build it as a HTML macro instead (you can do this inside your service provider.

```
HTML::macro('classLookUp', function()
{
     $route = Route::current();

     return Config::get('class'.$route);
}
```

So then to simply use this, put in your blade controller like so:

```
<div id="container" class="{{ HTML::classLookUp() }}"></div>
```

You might want to change up some of it, but the basic concept is there to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks It worked like a charm you are a life savior ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you try to change some layout variables based on controller method called.
You have to understand that service provider was created for other purposes. To manipulate layout variables it is better to use controller by calling $this->layout
Less code written not always means better quality. Sometimes it is better to write something extra just in case if someone else will work on this project in the future.

Also please don't call controllers from other controllers. It creates shagetti code. Use helpers instead.

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer . I don't want call a controller in another controller I just want to get controller instance which has been dispatched.
I agree with you that less code written not always means better quality but you should consider my situation. in my project I have so many pages and each page has a container element and each container class attribute is different from others and these classes are static and passing these class names in each action is not very readable and clean I need to have a switch case statement to set the class for each view depending on action.

Answer (score 0):

Since your setting a the class variable based on the controller and the function being called.

1. IndexController@getIndex - set layout class to homepage
2. IndexController@getHowworks  - set layout class to how-does-it-work

If your using the defaults and extending a BaseController:

```
    class BaseController extends \Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
      protected function setupLayout()
      {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
      }
   }
```

Then in your controller you should be able to do this:

```
public function getIndex()
{
  $this->layout->container_class = 'homepage';
  ... rest of controller code
}


public function getHowworks ()
{
  $this->layout->container_class = 'how-does-it-work';
  ... rest of controller code
}
```

Comment: thanks Terre but I just didn't want to pass a variable to layout in each action, instead write a switch case statement to set this variable upon controller and action which is called some other place but not in my controller.